# Apple TV UICollectionView margin bug

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, tvos

I have simple collection view in viewController. I have configured it with the following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(372, 200);
    layout.scrollDirection = UIAccessibilityScrollDirectionDown;
    self.collection.collectionViewLayout = layout;

    [self.collection registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    self.collection.dataSource = self;
    self.collection.delegate = self;
}
```

and I have 2 view cells. Please find codebase for cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

    return cell;
}
```

When this code run, it is looking like this.
[image]

If item width is changed with 373 and more than it is looking like this;

[image]

Cell Spacing must be zero but is not changing. Do anyone have any idea for this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. For your instance of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` you set minimal line and item spaces, not exact values. If you need to remove spaces between items you can reduce `sectionInset` of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Try this code:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    CGFloat leftMargin = 10.0;
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* collectionViewLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.collection.collectionViewLayout;
    CGFloat currentRowWidth = leftMargin;

    for (; currentRowWidth + collectionViewLayout.itemSize.width < self.collection.frame.size.width; currentRowWidth += collectionViewLayout.itemSize.width) {

    }
    CGFloat rightMargin = MAX(0.0, self.collection.frame.size.width - currentRowWidth);


    collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftMargin, 0, rightMargin);
    [collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is bug. Because, I defined sectionInset with right margin value being zero. You also set again it on viewDidLayoutSubviews for every child item. It works but if I want to set 1 px margin, must override viewDidLayoutSubviews. In addition, sectionInset defination on viewDidLoad is nonsense.

Comment: @BeyazBaron Yes, you already set sectionInset to zero, and on your screenshot sectionInset is zero (but the last item in a row has a bigger space to fit your requirement). If you want to have some margin at the begin of a row you need to make smaller right margin, that's all. I will modify my answer to show it.

Comment: I prepared an answer with your answer. I understood sectionInset logic. But if I set item width 372 px, everything is ok, however set 373 px default item margin shows. I think, it is bug. Thank you for everything.

Comment: @BeyazBaron It looks like an undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

SectionInset not item spacing. It is space of all UICollectionView. So calculate all items width with all items spaces on viewDidLoad following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);

    CGFloat itemWidth = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumInteritemSpacing;

    CGFloat allItemWitdh = itemWidth * (int)(_collection.frame.size.width / itemWidth);
    CGFloat rightMargin = _collection.frame.size.width - allItemWitdh;
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, rightMargin);

    layout.scrollDirection = UIAccessibilityScrollDirectionDown;
    self.collection.collectionViewLayout = layout;

    [self.collection registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that _collection will have correct size in viewDidLoad? This code fails If you create constraints dynamically or change _collection's frame. That's why I added my code into viewDidLayoutSubviews, because in this function you get the right size for all subviews.

Comment: Also, I see that you added the new property itemCount. Please update your question, I wrote my answer without this property.

Comment: @Roman Podymov, your answer is correct. I removed itemCount property on my code and didn't want to resize to collectionView. I needed to modify the collectionView just one time therefore just relocated your code on the viewDidLoad method. I checked your answer that correct. Thank you.